# another javascript function object question - more elegant way then using toString()

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, node.js

I turn to you with another Javascript object related question I was not able to find an answer so far.

I understand that functions are objects and that they do not have names. Instead variables are references to those objects.

```
> var a = function() {
... console.log('a');
... };
> a
[Function]
> typeof(a)
'function'
```

All this means that I can not ask a function for its name. I totally agree with that. But there is another case (putting the named function into an array) where I would be interested in the name and it is obviously there.

```
> var b = [function myname(){console.log('hi');},];
> b[0]
[Function: myname]
> b[0]();
hi
> typeof(b);
'object'
> typeof(b[0]);
'function'
```

In the later case I am wondering if  there is a more elegant way of asking for the name ("myname" in this case) then using toString()?

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the .name accessor

```
function helloworld() {}
console.log(helloworld.name); // outputs "helloworld"
var hello = function() {} // anonymous function, add a name
console.log(hello.name) // outputs ""
var hello = function hellow() {} //
console.log(hello.name) // outputs "hellow"
```

in chrome, console.dir() shows other properties of objects to help you further =]

Comment: Not only does this not work in IE, but also the `name` property is not part of any standard, so might stop working in future webkit/Gecko versions.

Answer (score 2):

you can use name property

`var b = [ function myname(){console.log('hi');} ];

console.log( b[0].name );`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to extract the name of a `function`, using a `Function prototype method`

```
Function.prototype.getMyName = function(){
   if (this.name) {
    return this.name;
   }
   var t = this.toString();
   return t.substring(0,t.indexOf('('))
           .replace(/function/i,'')
           .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
}

var b = [function myname(){console.log('hi');},];
b[0].getMyName(); //=> 'myname'
```

Comment: Might want to comment on how the constructor is affected by certain approaches to inheritance

Comment: @Russ Cam: there was no need for the `constructor`, my wrong. Adjusted the method and by the way added support for browsers that implemented the 'name' property.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.

The reason why you see the [function expression's identifier](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl) in console output is that console does call `toString()` internally.